# Is there any way to speed up the Selenium Server load time?

Tags: java, selenium

By design, Selenium makes a new copy of your Firefox profile each time a new test is run.  I find this copy time is a considerable bottleneck, especially when running 100s of tests.  (5-15 seconds to copy the profile anew).

Does anyone know of any override behavior for this?  I'd prefer my Selenium server to just reuse the same firefox profile.  I know this violates the "cleanly set up your test fixtures" philosophy, but it's a shortcut I'm willing to take, as my tests don't materially alter my firefox profile enough to jeopardize future tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree this is a problem. It's nice to have a new copy of a Firefox process each time, but  a bit overkill to double the startup time by regenerating the Firefox profile. If you open a bug report on http://jira.openqa.org and email me at patrick@browsermob.com I'll be happy to make sure we get a solution in place.

PS: I've solved this problem as a one-off for myself. We use the same Firefox profile and just nuke out the cache and cookies DB. But I really should just patch that change back to the Selenium source.

Comment: Can you explain how you solved this?  I would like to be able to re-use a browser object between tests also.

Comment: would also like the solution, please

Answer (score 6):

It's simply a matter of moving the code below outside of your test setup and into the fixture setup and keeping a global of the selenium instance (code assumes NUnit.)

```
[TestFixtureSetUp()]
public void FixtureSetup()
{
    selenium = New DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://localhost/");
    selenium.Start();
    selenium.SetTimeout("30000");
    selenium.Open("/");
}
```

Your test setup should then look something like this:

```
[SetUp()]
public void SetUpTest()
{
    selenium.Open("default.aspx");
    selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
}
```

Comment: Just wondering why you have a WaitForPageToLoad when this is inherent in the Open() method? It may just be that this is a 2009 post :-)

Answer (score 1):

One small way to reduce the time to load on the profile is to remove the larger files out of the firefox profile. In order to do so, set up your own profile by running the command firefox.exe -p. Once the profile is made, go into the options and turn off caching and other fluff that is not needed for the web tests. Then copy your profile to a new location and remove the sql files that are not needed. (otherwise when you open it up again, you restore the deleted files that keep the profile very small). When you start the selenium test, reference your profile in its new location.  Previous to this, I was copying over a 50MB profile at each test start-up, and now it copies over a 3-4MB profile, and the startup time is almost instant.

Again, this isnt a way to use the same profile again, but it will decrease your copy time of each profile.

Answer (score 0):

Using MSTest, I was able to get the driver to only open a single `Firefox` window for all tests, rather than opening and closing a new window for each test, by initialising the `WebDriver` in `ClassInitialize` (and `Cleanup`), rather than `TestInitialize`:

```
static string path;
        static IWebDriver driver;
        static string baseURL;

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext context) {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            path = Path.Combine(di.Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName, "Tests\\bin\\debug\\");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "http://localhost:5555/";
        }

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void ClassCleanup() {
            driver.Quit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it's an old question now!! Selenium server or RC is outdated but the same problem persists with Selenium Webdriver..it takes about 30 seconds to launch firefox through webdriver.

But as explained here some people got around this "After disabling unused Network adapters(located in Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections)

it was getting stuck at point:

```
ExtensionConnection connection = connectTo(exe.binary, profileToUse, "localhost");
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/a2fNfF-mD_E

Though it didn't work for me but one may want to try it for sure!!

Another wayout might be:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(@"path\to\firefox.exe");
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary,profile);
```